# I'm unable to locate/find xpath for the dropdown list in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, drop-down-menu

[image]I'm unable to locate/find xpath for the dropdown list in Selenium, Drop down is written with div tag and an attribute(aria-activedescendant) value is changing on hover. As soon as the value selected in the dropdown the attribute(aria-activedescendant) value is disappearing.

Any can help me to find xpath for this? Thanks in Advance.

HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="DropdownWidget---dropdown_value DropdownWidget---placeholder"
id="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_value" 
role="listbox" 
tabindex="0" 
aria-controls="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list" 
aria-expanded="false" 
aria-activedescendant="" 
aria-labelledby="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1" 
aria-describedby="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_selectedChoice" 
aria-required="true">
<!-- react-text: 38 -->- Please Select a Value -<!-- /react-text -->
<span id="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_selectedChoice" 
class="DropdownWidget---accessibilityhidden">- Please Select a Value -</span> 
</div>
```

Value of the attribute is changing on mouse hover as below:

```
aria-activedescendant=189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list_0
aria-activedescendant=189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list_1
aria-activedescendant=189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list_2
aria-activedescendant=189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list_3
```

Below is the inspected code for option:

```html
<div class="DropdownWidget---dropdown_value DropdownWidget---placeholder" id="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_value" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-controls="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list" aria-expanded="true" aria-activedescendant="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_list_2"
  aria-labelledby="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1" aria-describedby="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_selectedChoice" aria-required="true">
  <!-- react-text: 38 -->- Please Select a Value -
  <!-- /react-text --><span id="189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_selectedChoice" class="DropdownWidget---accessibilityhidden">- Please Select a Value -</span></div>
```

```
**Class used for dropdown selection**

public class Page2_ProjectType { 
WebDriver driver;
public Page2_ProjectType(WebDriver driver) {        
this.driver = driver;
}
public void MethodHome_ProjectType() throws InterruptedException {
Thread.sleep(5000);     
WebElement Btncreatenew = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"appian-body\"]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/a/img"));
Btncreatenew.click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
WebElement DDprojecttype = driver.findElement(By.id("189d67819beda8ebc9b5a2b7554f80f1_value"));
DDprojecttype.click();
String value = DDprojecttype.getAttribute("aria-activedescendant");
System.out.println(value);
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.DropdownWidget---dropdown_value.DropdownWidget---placeholder>span"));
for(WebElement element : options){
if(element.getText().equals("New Product Introduction")){
element.click();
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: why would anyone care about the attribute value which is being generated dynamically  by JS or any other programming language. If you want to select the drop down value , I don't think so aria-activedescendant would matter at all.

Comment: @cruisepandey  One of Dynamically changing values needs to be selected by WebDriver. Options available in dropdown are related to the attribute 'aria-activedescendant'. Can you please suggest any other way to sort out this?

Comment: can you show us your code and drop down values in HTML format

Comment: There is no html code is available regarding the options of dropdown, only the attribute value is changing that result in span tag value as well.

Comment: when you click manually on please select a value , I can see there are 3 options are being populated. just hover over to those options and inspect the element and share the same.

Comment: I can hover over the options, but if right click on them to inspect, the dropdown is closing that is dropdown is not frozen to inspect the options. I'm using JAVA for selenium

Comment: Hover action is being done over options and code is added in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**css selector** would be :

```
div.DropdownWidget---dropdown_value.DropdownWidget---placeholder>span.DropdownWidget---accessibilityhidden
```

**UPDATE:**

your drop down is constructed using **div** and **span** tags.

**code** you can try out :

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(by.cssSelector("div.DropdownWidget---dropdown_value.DropdownWidget---placeholder>span"));
for(WebElement element : options){
 if(element.getText().equals("New Product Introduction")){
    element.click();
}
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code under update section, Note that it will select New Product Introduction from the drop down.

Comment: Test is PASSED, but option is not clicked in UI :( I have added my class file in the Question, kindly refer that also.

Comment: Are you clicking on drop down first ? After that the script provided by me will work. And also can you check the size of list ?

Comment: options.size() , print this.

Comment: options.size() returns the value '1'

Comment: It should return 4. or depends how many options you have in your drop down.

Comment: As i mentioned in question, on mouse hover over options attribute 'aria-activedescendant' is changing. So i have tried to do `moveByOffset` along with `Click` it isn't working as well.

Comment: Thanks for providing insights! I have sorted this using `Sendkeys` and `keys.ENTER`

Comment: @RajiMuthukumar : If you think this answer was helpful , then you can accept this answer by clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button and besides my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(., 'New Product Introduction')]")));
option.click();
...
```

instead of:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.DropdownWidget---dropdown_value.DropdownWidget---placeholder>span"));
for(WebElement element : options){
   if(element.getText().equals("New Product Introduction")){
      element.click();
   }
}
```

After click that opens your dropdown, wait until element will be clickable and only than click on it.

Comment: Thanks for providing insights! I have sorted this using `Sendkeys` and `keys.ENTER`

Comment: @RajiMuthukumar If my answer was useful you can mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button. And/or upvote it ))

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Cruisepandey and @Andrei Suvorkov, I have used below code to locate and enter the option in dropdown.

```
WebElement projectType = driver.findElement(By.id("_value"));
projectType.sendKeys("New Product Introduction");
projectType.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```